# Plotting a tree with lengths of different branches given, All growing in 'Y' shape with angles specified

Tags: matlab, tree, fractals

I need to create branching as seen in neurons. Help me with the algorithm for this. A simple algorithm to mimic this branching pattern. Later need to add complexities.

Here's the code written by me in MATLAB. But there's something wrong with angles. I am unable to get a proper tree.

```
x1=400;
x2=x1+200;
y1=200;
y2=200;
plot([x1 x2],[y1 y2],'b-');
array1=[];
array2=[];
array3=[];
h=4;
array1=[x1,y1];
[m,n]=size(array1);
k=0;
theta1=150;
theta2=-150;
while(k<4)
for i=1:1:m
        x01=array1(i,1);
        y01=array1(i,2);
        x0=x01;
        y0=y01;
        theta1=theta1-30;
        theta2=theta2-30;


    for j=1:2
        x1=x0-h;

        if(j==1)
          slop1 = tand(theta1);
          y1 = ((x1-x0)*(slop1))+y0;
        else
          slop1 = tand(theta2);
          y1 = ((x1-x0)*(slop1))+y0;
        end

          array2=[array2;x1,y1];   
          plot([x0  x1],[y0 y1],'b-');
    end   
end

array1=[];
array1=array2;
array2=[];
[m,n]=size(array1);
k=k+1;
end
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? perhaps some code and an idea of what language you are working in? SO is a place to find help when you're stuck at a specific problem, not a place to solve all of your issues without work on your part.

Comment: I want to plot the branching in MATLAB. I am basically trying to plot the branching in neurons: It is similar to that in trees. I am considering different Y's: 2,4,8,16 and so on. I have plotted it, but couldn't get the angles properly.

Comment: thanks for the code and, can you edit your question to include the `[matlab]` tag, so the right people can see it.

Comment: Just as an idea: you might want to have a look at [L-Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-system)